# KDevelop 4.2.2 syntax highlighting questions

Tags: c++, kdevelop4

For my C++ development I am running KDevelop on Ubuntu Natty, I have two questions:

1) It highlights all my variables in random rainbow colors - how can I change that? I want all my variables in light blue.

2) The functions color is always purple, how can I change that?

I'd appreciate if someone knows the answer.

Thank you!!

Comment: I didn't know people were actually using KDevelop.  How is that working out for you?

Comment: I am evaluating the switch to KDevelop after having tried many other alternatives for PHP development. I am sick of Eclipse, Netbeans and the others, which are all Java-based, slow as hell, and complicated like no other software on earth... It's quite good. Only showstopper is that you can't debug PHP projects...

Answer (score 7):

The answer to both your questions is simple: at the moment you cannot.

You can make sure that all variables are highlighted in the same color, but this color will be black and cannot be changed. Go to

> Settings -> Configure KDevelop... -> Language Support

And make sure that in the `Semantic Code Highlighting` part both `Local Colorization Intensity` and `Global Colorization Intensity` are set to zero (i.e. slide the slider to the left).

However, why would you want this? Personally, I find it very convenient to have a different color for every variable. It lets you very easily spot all occurrences of a particular variable.

Comment: The default setting gave me a bit of a headache :) Sliding those cursors just a bit to the left and the pain was gone. Thanks for sharing this, would have never figured out...

Comment: even set to 0, the variables are not black :/ quite weird such a functionality couldn't be disabled O.O

Comment: I find it very annoying honestly, too many colors on screen and the syntax becomes a mess to make out. I personally prefer things more like what IDEA delivers, but IDEA can't work with C/++.

Comment: Can't believe after 11 years this is still a question..

> However, why would you want this? Personally,

Exactly.. "personally" - people are different. I was tearing (what remains of) my hair out trying to figure out why the syntax highlighting scheme I created wasn't being reflected in the editor.

This setting needs to be moved to (or at least linked to) the colour scheme editor.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah... the source code is quite "poor"... there are many hard coded values with no options to change them... Fortunately, it's open source ;)

I ran out with the same problem : I agree, the rainbow color increase readability in some ways but personally, it distracts me... So I did this patch to kdevplatform :

```
  diff -aur -x '*.user' -x CMakeFiles kdevplatform-1.7.0-o/language/highlighting/colorcache.cpp kdevplatform-1.7.0-n/language/highlighting/colorcache.cpp
  --- kdevplatform-1.7.0-o/language/highlighting/colorcache.cpp 2014-08-26 19:49:48.000000000 +0000
  +++ kdevplatform-1.7.0-n/language/highlighting/colorcache.cpp 2014-10-23 19:50:37.667559094 +0000
  @@ -43,37 +43,38 @@

  #define ifDebug(x)

  -// ######### start interpolation
  +//// ######### start interpolation

  -uint totalColorInterpolationStepCount = 6;
  -uint interpolationWaypoints[] = {0xff0000, 0xff9900, 0x00ff00, 0x00aaff, 0x0000ff, 0xaa00ff};
  -//Do less steps when interpolating to/from green: Green is very dominant, and different mixed green tones are hard to distinguish(and always seem green).
  -uint interpolationLengths[] = {0xff, 0xff, 0xbb, 0xbb, 0xbb, 0xff};
  -
  -uint totalGeneratedColors = 10;
  -
  -uint totalColorInterpolationSteps()
  -{
  -  uint ret = 0;
  -  for(uint a = 0; a < totalColorInterpolationStepCount; ++a)
  -    ret += interpolationLengths[a];
  -  return ret;
  -}
  -
  -///Generates a color from the color wheel. @param step Step-number, one of totalColorInterpolationSteps
  -QColor interpolate(uint step)
  -{
  -  uint waypoint = 0;
  -  while(step > interpolationLengths[waypoint]) {
  -    step -= interpolationLengths[waypoint];
  -    ++waypoint;
  -  }
  -
  -  uint nextWaypoint = (waypoint + 1) % totalColorInterpolationStepCount;
  -
  -  return KColorUtils::mix( QColor(interpolationWaypoints[waypoint]), QColor(interpolationWaypoints[nextWaypoint]),
  -                           float(step) / float(interpolationLengths[waypoint]) );
  -}
  +//uint totalColorInterpolationStepCount = 6;
  +//uint interpolationWaypoints[] = {0xff0000, 0xff9900, 0x00ff00, 0x00aaff, 0x0000ff, 0xaa00ff};
  +////Do less steps when interpolating to/from green: Green is very dominant, and different mixed green tones are hard to distinguish(and always seem green).
  +//uint interpolationLengths[] = {0xff, 0xff, 0xbb, 0xbb, 0xbb, 0xff};
  +
  +//uint totalGeneratedColors = 10;
  +
  +//uint totalColorInterpolationSteps()
  +//{
  +//  uint ret = 0;
  +//  for(uint a = 0; a < totalColorInterpolationStepCount; ++a)
  +//    ret += interpolationLengths[a];
  +//  return ret;
  +//}
  +
  +/////Generates a color from the color wheel. @param step Step-number, one of totalColorInterpolationSteps
  +
  +//QColor interpolate(uint step)
  +//{
  +//  uint waypoint = 0;
  +//  while(step > interpolationLengths[waypoint]) {
  +//    step -= interpolationLengths[waypoint];
  +//    ++waypoint;
  +//  }
  +
  +//  uint nextWaypoint = (waypoint + 1) % totalColorInterpolationStepCount;
  +
  +//  return KColorUtils::mix( QColor(interpolationWaypoints[waypoint]), QColor(interpolationWaypoints[nextWaypoint]),
  +//                           float(step) / float(interpolationLengths[waypoint]) );
  +//}

  // ######### end interpolation
  namespace KDevelop {
  @@ -144,6 +145,7 @@
     m_defaultColors = new CodeHighlightingColors(this);

     m_colors.clear();
  +  /*
     uint step = totalColorInterpolationSteps() / totalGeneratedColors;
     uint currentPos = m_colorOffset;
     ifDebug(kDebug() << "text color:" << m_foregroundColor;)
  @@ -152,6 +154,7 @@
     ifDebug(kDebug() << "color" << a << "interpolated from" << currentPos << " < " << totalColorInterpolationSteps() << ":" << (void*) m_colors.last().rgb();)
     currentPos += step;
     }
  +  */
     m_validColorCount = m_colors.count();
     m_colors.append(m_foregroundColor);
  }
```

it removes the color generated, so that variables are now really black (foreground color).

for the 2) it seems the current version respects the kate syntax color (not sure).

on Archlinux I also did this PKGBUILD :

```
  pkgname=kdevplatform-no-rainbow-highlight
  _pkgname=kdevplatform without rainbow colors highlighting
  pkgver=1.7.0
  _pkgver=4.7.0
  pkgrel=2
  pkgdesc="A C/C++ development platform for KDE"
  arch=('i686' 'x86_64')
  url="http://www.kdevelop.org/"
  license=('GPL')
  provides=('kdevplatform')
  conflicts=('kdevplatform')
  depends=('kdelibs' 'subversion' 'qjson')
  optdepends=("kdesdk-kompare: difference checking")
  makedepends=('cmake' 'automoc4' 'boost')
  install="${_pkgname}.install"
  source=("http://download.kde.org/stable/kdevelop/${_pkgver}/src/${_pkgname}-${pkgver}.tar.xz"
        "no-rainbow-color.patch"
  )
  sha1sums=('9fc196e7cb09ab33fd5cfbf5af19aa7c513efdc9'
           'bed3c7e470a6a5a56bf1611e0effd7b8a8761e33')

  prepare() {
  cd ${_pkgname}-${pkgver}
  patch -p1 -i ${srcdir}/no-rainbow-color.patch
  cd ${srcdir}
  mkdir build
  }

  build() {
  cd build
  cmake ../${_pkgname}-${pkgver} \
     -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr \
     -DCMAKE_SKIP_RPATH=ON \
     -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release
  make
  }

  package() {
  cd build
  make DESTDIR="${pkgdir}" install
  }
```

Answer (score -2):

Do not get rid of variables with different colors, you will ask yourself how you did in the past without it.

Comment: For future reference, only answer a question if you actually plan on answering the question at hand. If you want to share your opinion go to chat.